# How do you hide the key, salt, and iv when using openssl from appearing in your process title?

Tags: linux, security, openssl, aes

When using openssl to encrypt/decrypt data and the AES cipher, my command will look something like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in message_file -K 42AB7FCE7BFEEE03E16719044916CBD475F6D000F230D213FF0F4775EF8D46F5 -iv D5C21AC249B26A1FBA376E8CFCDC4E1A -S 2C6A1B8EAACA302D -e -out message_file.enc
```

This places the key, iv, and salt in my process title that is visible in top/ps. Is there a way to AES encrypt a file with openssl (or even another alternative if not) without revealing this information? I did not see an option to grab these strings from files.

Answer (score 1):

RSA encryption:

http://bsdsupport.org/q-how-do-i-use-openssl-to-encrypt-files/

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.key -in plaintext.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

AES encryption:

Based on the results of openssl enc -h

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in foo -out foo.enc -kfile passwordfile
```

And here's the result of openssl enc -h.  Note the description of -kfile

```
root@bt:/tmp# openssl enc -h
unknown option '-h'
options are
-in <file>     input file
-out <file>    output file
-pass <arg>    pass phrase source
-e             encrypt
-d             decrypt
-a/-base64     base64 encode/decode, depending on encryption flag
-k             passphrase is the next argument
-kfile         passphrase is the first line of the file argument
-md            the next argument is the md to use to create a key
                 from a passphrase.  One of md2, md5, sha or sha1
-K/-iv         key/iv in hex is the next argument
-[pP]          print the iv/key (then exit if -P)
-bufsize <n>   buffer size
-engine e      use engine e, possibly a hardware device.
Cipher Types
-aes-128-cbc               -aes-128-cfb               -aes-128-cfb1             
-aes-128-cfb8              -aes-128-ecb               -aes-128-ofb              
-aes-192-cbc               -aes-192-cfb               -aes-192-cfb1             
-aes-192-cfb8              -aes-192-ecb               -aes-192-ofb              
-aes-256-cbc               -aes-256-cfb               -aes-256-cfb1             
-aes-256-cfb8              -aes-256-ecb               -aes-256-ofb              
-aes128                    -aes192                    -aes256                   
-bf                        -bf-cbc                    -bf-cfb                   
-bf-ecb                    -bf-ofb                    -blowfish                 
-cast                      -cast-cbc                  -cast5-cbc                
-cast5-cfb                 -cast5-ecb                 -cast5-ofb                
-des                       -des-cbc                   -des-cfb                  
-des-cfb1                  -des-cfb8                  -des-ecb                  
-des-ede                   -des-ede-cbc               -des-ede-cfb              
-des-ede-ofb               -des-ede3                  -des-ede3-cbc             
-des-ede3-cfb              -des-ede3-ofb              -des-ofb                  
-des3                      -desx                      -desx-cbc                 
-rc2                       -rc2-40-cbc                -rc2-64-cbc               
-rc2-cbc                   -rc2-cfb                   -rc2-ecb                  
-rc2-ofb                   -rc4                       -rc4-40
```

Comment: This uses RSA, but i want to use AES.

Comment: kfile is for passphrase, but that is not the same as the Key in hex, option -k

Answer (score 1):

openssl can take commands from stdin

For example if `onetime_keyfile` specifies the key and IV with the following contents

```
-K 42AB7FCE7BFEEE03E16719044916CBD475F6D000F230D213FF0F4775EF8D46F5 -iv D5C21AC249B26A1FBA376E8CFCDC4E1A
```

Then the following commands will encrypt a file using that information

```
umask 077
echo -n "enc -aes-256-cbc -in message_file -out message_file.enc " > encrypt_command_file
cat onetime_keyfile >> encrypt_command_file
openssl < encrypt_command_file
```

Note that in your question you specify both key, initialization vector and salt. The salt argument is ignored in that case; salt is only used to derive key and iv from a pass phrase. If you specify key and iv explicitly, then you should use your own salt algorithm to generate a unique key and iv for each file that you encrypt. So in practical use, the file onetime_keyfile in the example above should be generated as output from another program.

Refer to https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html for details of the standard algorithm for generating key and IV from pass phrase and salt.

If you are not doing your own salting, you are probably better to use the -kfile or -pass option to read a pass phrase from a file.